# Docker multi-stage build : can't copy using extension from previous stage

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am dockerizing a maven app
My dockerfile looks like ..

```
FROM maven:3.8-openjdk-11 AS maven_builder

ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir -pv $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ADD . $APP_HOME

RUN mvn clean install

FROM tomcat:8.5.43-jdk8
COPY --from=maven_builder /app/target/test.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

This one works fine !
But, I want to modify the last COPY command in such a way, so that I can copy all the .war & .jar files at location /app/target

I tried something like ...

```
COPY --from=maven_builder /app/target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
COPY --from=maven_builder /app/target/*.jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

And

```
COPY --from=maven_builder /app/target/*.{war,jar} /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

But, then build logs say : `"message":"COPY failed: no source files were specified"`

Is this possible , if yes, then how ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: The doc says the destination must be a directory and should end with a / . Maybe try this `COPY --from=maven_builder /app/target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/`

Comment: @StephaneM, tried this.. getting the same results with OR without "/" after "webapps"